# ASP.Net MVC Access the SSRS reports and export them to pdf without using ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, reporting-services

So, I am using SSRS to generate reports and I have a server where my reports are stored.
Now I need to download them and I have this code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Export(string id)
{
     NetworkCredential nwc = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     client.Credentials = nwc;
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

     client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

     string reportURL = "http://desktop-4gpisbo:8080/teste/report/RelatorioPrincipal/&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Parameters=false&id=" + id;
     return File(client.DownloadData(reportURL), "application/pdf");
}
```

But it is giving me a PDF that is impossible to open or when it opens it says that is unavailable.
The `id` is being passed via `JQuery` in my view, where it gets the `Id` from the `URL` then sends it to the controller, because my report is dynamic, I need different information depending on the user.

What is wrong with this code ?

P.S : The report is running on my localhost not on a server

Comment: Can you not invoke the reports via the Report execution web service that is exposed via SSRS? You can then return the report in PDF format!

Comment: How do I do  that ?

Comment: Are you using compiled .rdl 's for the reports created in SQL Server Business Intelligence Dev Studio? ....and then uploading them to your SSRS reporting server.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void SetDataSources(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DataSources.Add(new 
         ReportDataSource("DataSources1",TempData["DataSources1"]));
               
     }

 public FileResult ExportToPDF(TableViewModel data, string setToken)
  {
     var ProjectsList = from project in ProjectList
                        select new
                        {
                            project.ID,
                            project.Name,
                                  
                        };

            ReportViewer ProjectListReportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = 
            Server.MapPath("~/Views/Reports/Reprot.rdlc");
            ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource rdc = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ProjectsList);

        
            ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new 
            SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SetProjectsDetail);
            ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdc);
            ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            byte[] bytes = ProjectListReportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, 
              out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, ouwarnings);
            
            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new 
            HttpCookie("getToken", setToken));
 return File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Report.pdf");
        }
```